# Can people steal loot in my treasury?

Tags: clash-of-clans

In the treasury it says

> Clan War and Star Bonus loot is greatly protected inside the Treasury.—

Does this mean that people town hall 9 or lower or the same as me can steal loot? Or is there a certain percentage that they can take? (I'm town hall 9)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, people can still take loot from your treasury. While watching a replay, you may have seen that when troops attack a gold storage, gold coins bounce off it and "loot gained" bar grows. Similarly when troops attack the clan castle, gold bounces off it which proves that people can take loot from treasury
But it is only a small amount(Before this treasury update, people could take huge amount of loot from treasury)

Source: Personal Experience